# Assistance with writing out this script to an excel file

Tags: excel, powershell

I have this script that reads in a list of computernames and writes out networking details on each VM (IP, Subnet, Gateway, DNS Servers, MAC).  It works in that the script writes out to my powershell window.  I'm trying to add in some code to write the output to a .csv file.  Here is my script:

```
    $inputFile = "C:\Powershell_Scripts\IP_Mac\servers.txt"
    $csvFile = "C:\Powershell_Scripts\IP_Mac\results.csv"

 $report = @()

 foreach($Computer in (gc -Path $inputFile)){
  if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0) {
   $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}
   foreach ($Network in $Networks) {
    $IPAddress  = $Network.IpAddress[0]
    $SubnetMask  = $Network.IPSubnet[0]
    $DefaultGateway = $Network.DefaultIPGateway
    $DNSServers  = $Network.DNSServerSearchOrder
    $IsDHCPEnabled = $false
    If($network.DHCPEnabled) {
     $IsDHCPEnabled = $true
    }
    $MACAddress  = $Network.MACAddress
    $OutputObj  = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value $IPAddress
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SubnetMask -Value $SubnetMask
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Gateway -Value ($DefaultGateway -join “,”)
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsDHCPEnabled -Value $IsDHCPEnabled
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DNSServers -Value $DNSServers
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MACAddress -Value $MACAddress
    $OutputObj
   }
  }
 }
     Write-Output $report
#}  

#When writing out the data in $node, use the tags defined in $properties to write out to a .csv file
$report | Select-Object -Property $properties | Export-Csv -Path $csvFile -NoTypeInformation
```

It's something with my last line when I'm writing out the report.  Any help you can provide on how to write the results to a file would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the `$Properties` variable being set?

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding anything to your $report array, change the last `$OutputObj` line

```
...
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MACAddress 
             -Value $MACAddress
$OutputObj
}
...
```

to

```
...
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MACAddress 
             -Value $MACAddress
$report += ,$OutputObj
}
...
```

and last line

```
$report | Select-Object -Property $properties |
          Export-Csv -Path $csvFile -NoTypeInformation
```

to

```
$report | Export-Csv -Path $csvFile -NoTypeInformation
```

To capture details of machines you can't connect to you could change line 8 to:

```
try{
    $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration 
    -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}
}
catch{
    Write-Output($Computer + "`t" + $_.Exception.Message ) | 
    Out-File "C:\Powershell_Scripts\IP_Mac\bad_computers.tsv"
}
```

and you will get a tsv file with computer name and error message.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the suggestion! My code is working and writing out to a .csv file now.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the suggestion! My code is working and writing out to a .csv file now.
I'm wondering how I would modify this code a bit to not exclude any computers in my input list that may not be accessible.  I've seen some errors in my Powershell window saying access id denied.  I would like to write out at least the computername of which one had a problem during my scan so I can identify which ones I need to look into.